# How can i align the text of the radio button to the left of the button

Tags: android, radio-button

How to align the text to the left of radio button array?

```
       RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[answerOption.size()];

       for (int i = 0; i < answerOption.size(); i++) {
        rb[i] = new RadioButton(getContext());
        rb[i].setButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLUE));
        rb[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        rg.addView(rb[i]);
        rb[i].setText(i);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
android:button="@null"
android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
```

or also u can try

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

Comment: the fourth element of radio group get shifted to first...so the index changes

Comment: No it wont happen

Comment: try this  android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:layout_gravity="start"

Comment: the first works in the case if i had radio button in xml declared,but i only have a radio group

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

On Xml

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:textAlignment="textStart"
android:layout_gravity="start"
```

Change this Code Java file

```
int i;
RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[answerOption.size()];
for (i = 0; i < answerOption.size(); i++) {
   rb[i] = new RadioButton(getContext());    
}
rb[i].setButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLUE));
rb[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
rb[i].setText(i);
rg.addView(rb[i]);
```

Comment: addView method is called two times,so it is throwing exceotion

Comment: remove last line    rg.addView(rb[i]);

Comment: it works but i want the index of radio button unchanged,as it changes the index of last element to first element

Comment: use this Collections.sort(answerOption); in above int i

Comment: u are right but i want the index not  the value of button